# No sound from mac, how to find the problem?

Tags: audio, headphones

Good day, I have Macbook Pro 2012 with el Capitan 10.11.3.

The problem - no sound from my mac.

I have listen the music, after that I decide to insert headphones, when I'm taking out the headphones sound from Mac disappeared and there is red light from audio jack. Between that I have made an update from 10.11 to 10.11.3, maybe the problem is with that?

There was not any sound from my mac on startup, but when I have use disk utility repair the sound on startup appears..

How can I diagnose myself where is the problem and fix it ?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Your MacBook believes you've plugged in an optical audio cable when you haven't.**

Turns out, that headphone jack is actually a combo jack that has both optical audio and analog audio. [There's a little lever in there that detects when you've put a cable in there that's probably stuck.](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/macbook-pro-optical-out-wont-turn-off.239287/) Try fiddling with a toothpick or repeatedly plugging and unplugging.

Answer (score -1):

Try **holding down option** and **clicking on the sound icon** in the menu bar at the top of the screen. It'll give you a few options you can tweak.

My guess is that you're most likely AirPlaying your sound to muted speakers.

[image]

Comment: This icon is gray{

Comment: Nope: Notice the mention of a red light and the system preferences pane outputting to "Optical". See my answer